# phantomJS : Absolute path working, but Relative path giving problems

Tags: php, javascript, linux, phantomjs

I'm on a Linux web server. The following files are being used to create a screenshot:

- ons.php
- ong.js
- ons2.php

All these files along with `phantomJS` binary are in the same folder. The folder's permission is `744`

### ons.php

```
$forMonth = date('M Y');
exec('./phantomjs ons.js '.strtotime($forMonth), $op, $er);
print_r($op);
echo $er;
```

### ons.js

```
var args = require('system').args;
var dt = '';
args.forEach(function(arg, i) {

    if(i == 1)
    {
        dt = arg;       
    }   

});
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('./ons2.php?dt='+dt, function () { //<--- This is failing
    page.render('./xx.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

### ons2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>How are you</title>
</head> 
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['dt']))
{

    echo $_GET['dt'];

}
else
{
    echo '<h1>Did not work</h1>';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

On opening `ons.php` in the browser, I'm getting this result:

```
Array ( ) 0
```

But no screenshot is being created.

## Debugging

On debugging a lot, I found out that it has to do with paths.

--> If I put the following inside `ons.js`

```
.
.
.   
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.abc.com/ppt/ons2.php', function () { // <-- absolute path
    page.render('./xx.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

The screenshot is getting created. I want to avoid using absolute paths as the application will be shifted to a different domain pretty soon.

What I don't get is why relative path is not working even if all files are in the same folder. Is my syntax of `page.open('./ons2.php....')` wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./ons2.php` implies a **local** file. It **will not** be passed through to the web server, and moreover it will fail outright because you also appended a query string - in the local file system this would be treated as part of the file name, so the file will not be located at all.

You will **need** to supply an absolute URL for this to work as you expect - but you *can* determine this dynamically in PHP (using `$_SERVER`) and pass it in to the JS script as a command line argument.

For example (untested):

### ons.php

```
<?php

    // Determine the absolute URL of the directory containing this script
    $baseURL = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' ? 'https' : 'http')
             . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
             . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '/') . '/';

    $now = new DateTime('now'); // Because all the cool kids use DateTime

    $cmd = './phantomjs ons.js '
         . escapeshellarg($now->format('M Y')) . ' ' // Don't forget to escape args!
         . escapeshellarg($baseURL)
         . ' 2>&1'; // let's capture STDERR as well

    // Do your thang
    exec($cmd, $op, $er);

    print_r($op);
    echo $er;
```

### ons.js

```
var args, url, page;

args = require('system').args;
if (args.length < 3) {
    console.error('Invalid arguments');
    phantom.exit();
}

url = args[2] + 'ons2.php?dt=' + encodeURIComponent(args[1]);

console.log('Loading page: ' + url);

page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function () {
    page.render('./xx.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

ons2.php remains the same.

Comment: Just a doubt --> What is the purpose of `2>&1` I assume it writes a file to disk, does it? And if yes where will it be stored and with what name?

Comment: @asprin `2>&1` redirects STDERR to STDOUT, in effect it means that PHP receives any errors that are printed as well as the regular output. In production you probably wouldn't want it to be there - you certainly wouldn't want to show it to the user - that's mostly for debugging purposes. It doesn't cause anything to be written to disk though, it just attaches one output stream to another. Similarly the `console.log();` line is only really there for debugging purposes, although it's probably worth leaving the `console.error()` line in there.

Comment: Yeh, I'm aware of `console.log()`..`stderr` is new to me. Not really a linux person xd Thanks again.

Comment: @asprin FYI STDERR isn't specifically a *nix thing, it works the same way on Windows (including `2>&1` syntax). [Info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) and [excellent source of information](http://ss64.com/) about various shells and other languages/DSLs ([relevant page](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue in page.render but I don't think so. The most common case of hangs is unhandled exception.

I will suggest you 4 things to investigate the issue :

- add an handler to [phantom.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html) and/or to [page.OnError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html)
- encapsulate your code in try/catch blocks (such as for page.render)
- Once the page is loaded, there is no test on callback status. It's better to check the status ('success' or 'fail')
- seems to freeze when calling page.render. Have you tried a simpler filename in the current directory? Maybe the freeze is because of the security or invalid filename (invalid characters?)

Hope this will help you

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, where exactly inside `ons.js` should I place the `phantom.onError` code? Should it be right after `page.open`?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get what you want meant by `open links. Just code in the js script`. However, I did put some callback on `page.open` and seems that it's failing. I'm updating my question with more debugging code.

Comment: sorry, just want to say : copy & paste the js code from the wiki